# Override bulma variables in Nuxt.js project generated with Buefy UI?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

I created a nuxt.js project and chose buefy as the UI framework, everything works fine, however, I can't access Bulma's variables to change the colors of the "is-primary" class of a button, for example, is there any way to be able to modify bulma sass variables using buefy as UI framework?

This is a piece of my nuxt.config.js file at the root of the project:

```js
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
    'nuxt-buefy',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],
```

Here's how the file is imported into .nuxt/App.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { decode, parsePath, withoutBase, withoutTrailingSlash, normalizeURL } from 'ufo'

import { getMatchedComponentsInstances, getChildrenComponentInstancesUsingFetch, promisify, globalHandleError, urlJoin, sanitizeComponent } from './utils'
import NuxtError from '..\\layouts\\error.vue'
import NuxtLoading from './components/nuxt-loading.vue'
import NuxtBuildIndicator from './components/nuxt-build-indicator'

import '..\\node_modules\\buefy\\dist\\buefy.css'

import _6f6c098b from '..\\layouts\\default.vue'
```

And finally my buefy.js in the .nuxt/buefy.js path:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'

Vue.use(Buefy, {
  "css": true,
  "materialDesignIcons": true,
  "materialDesignIconsHRef": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.8.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
  "async": true
})
```

What I want is to change, for example, the background color of this button:

```html
<button class="button is-success is-outlined is-rounded">
              <strong>Cadastre-se</strong>
</button>
```

I want to change the background color of is-success when it is active, the variables are [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/#variables):

Comment: I don't know how I would apply this to my current buefy structure with nuxt.js: https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it!

First, we changed the modules of our nuxt.config.js/ts to:

```js
modules: [
    ['nuxt-buefy', { css: false}],    
  ],
```

It's important that the buefy's css is false so that we can set the scss here:

```js
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss',
  ]
```

Now just create the main.scss in the directory that you define in css and modify it your way. In my case, I changed the variables that color the primary buttons.